# GWT - DateBox / DatePicker issues for invalid dates in Internet Explorer 8

Tags: gwt, internet-explorer-8, datepicker

The DatePicker/DateBox I'm using has a text field for the year. If I put my cursor in the box and start typing, it concatenates on the end (ie, it starts out as 2013 and turns into 20132012). If I then pick a date and submit, the year gets changed automatically to be 1969. Presumably this is because the date is out of range. However, when I try to edit the year again to fix it, it automatically reverts to 1969 no matter what I type. This only happens in Internet Explorer 8.

Is this a known issue? Is there anything I can do to make the experience more user-friendly?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: "The DatePicker/DateBox I'm using" which one is it? Can you show your code?

Comment: It seems to be both. I am trying to fix old code, and I don't fully understand how it's put together. Unfortunately the error presents only on deployed code, not my own, so it's very difficult to narrow down.

Comment: The work-around that I have found is to make it so that a year with more than 4 digits cannot be entered.. it will simply do a substring.

Comment: The problem still exists overall that it breaks on a large year.

Comment: I meant: did you mean `com.google.gwt.user.datepicker.DateBox` or a widget from some 3rd-party library? DateBox is probably not meant to enter only dates. An IntegerBox would probably work better here.